# View fadeout animation and start new activity

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, view, fadeout

Ok well, what I'm trying to do is :
to fade out the current activity that it is all an ImageView,
and start new  activity.

But what I'm getting is :
the view fade out very well but when the animation ends it show me for like half sec
the same view and after that it start the new Activity.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks ahead.

Here is my code :

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity{

ImageView enterImage;
Button next;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
     enterImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.enterImg);
     next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
     next.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fadeOutAndHideImage(enterImage);
        }
    });

}

private void fadeOutAndHideImage(final ImageView img)
  {
    Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
    fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    fadeOut.setDuration(1500);

    fadeOut.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()
    {
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) 
            {
                finish();
                Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
    });

    img.startAnimation(fadeOut);


}
```

Comment: delete the finish(); line and see if that works for you!

Comment: It's not something I've ever tried to do but my guess is simply as you're obviously not animating the fade out of the `Activity` but simply the content view. When starting another `Activity` there will be a short delay in that transition and this is what you're experiencing.

Comment: Try using a single `Activity` with `Fragments` instead of two `Activities`. You can apply animations to how the `Fragments` disappear when replaced and when the new one appears.

Comment: what do you mean about one activity with fragments? can you give me an example ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you're fading out the image rather than the activity. The new activity takes a little time to appear after you actually make the call for it to appear and in that time it is showing you the old view.

Try putting the `finish();` AFTER `startActivity(i);` that way the closing animation of the old activity is hidden behind the entrance of the new activity then you can avoid the problem while keeping the custom image fading that you've implemented.

EDIT: Try using this on both Activities: `Activity.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);` This needs to be put in both `onCreate()` and `onPause()` methods .